# Django Model inheritance and access children based on category

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I want to get the parent class values with each child values? How can I identify child objects to fetch?

I have the Django model structure like this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')


class PizzaRestaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class PastaRestaurant(Place):
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

When we do operation we may save the object like below. And it saved into the db as i expected. two entry in the Place table and each entry in each child object table.

```
a = Category()
a.name = "pasta"

b = Category()
b.name = "pizza"

a.save()
b.save()

x = PastaRestaurant()
x.address = "Pasta Address"
x.name = "Pastamonia"
x.extra = "some extra"
x.category = a

y = PizzaRestaurant()
y.address = "Pizza Address"
y.name = "Dominos"
y.serves_hot_dogs = 1
y.serves_pizza = 0
y.category = b

x.save()
y.save()
```

Now I need to access the like this

```
p = Place.objects.get(id=1)
```

How can I know, which objects/attributes belongs to the place objects?
So when I fetch the place with common attributes and should be able get the corresponding child objects values also.

Or any other model design work for my need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the child model's attributes you need to fetch it as that model, i e `PizzaRestaurant` or `PastaRestaurant`, otherwise you will only get a `Place` object.

If you need to get all Places regardless of subclass take a look at [InheritanceManager](http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) from `django-model-utils`. Using this you can implement overloaded operations to perform subclass-specific actions.

Comment: django-model-utils supports Django 1.4 through 1.9. It is not for current release 1.10 ? for the new releases of Django We dont know this is work ?

Comment: I use it with 1.10 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

[django-polymorphic](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic) does this beautifully, improving the abilities to work with model inheritance like so:

from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

```
class Place(PolymorphicModel):
    ...

class PizzaRestaurant(Place):
    ...

class PastaRestaurant(Place:
    ...


>>> some_place = Place.objects.create(name="Walmart")
>>> some_pizza_place = PizzaRestaurant.objects.create(name="Slice King", address="101 Main St., Bismarck, ND", category = Category.objects.first(),serves_pizza=True)
>>> some_pizza_place.instance_of(PizzaPlace)
True
>>> PizzaRestaurant.objects.all()
queryset<['Slice King',]>
>>> Place.objects.all()
queryset<['Walmart', 'Slice King',]>
```

Comment: How this will support with django-rest framework and serializers ?